# Cannot Handle Tweenlite Re-Play[ActionScript3]

Tags: actionscript-3, gsap

I am trying to make a continuous motion. And I use tweenlite, and want it restart when done. Here is the code;

```
     public function npcMotions()
     {
        var speed_cop,speed_hyvn:Number;

        speed_cop = randomHandler(1,5);
        speed_hyvn = randomHandler(1,5);

        TweenLite.to(cop_bir, speed_cop, {y:500,ease:Linear.easeNone,delay:0,onComplete:fixedUpdate});
        TweenLite.to(balik, speed_hyvn, {y:500,ease:Linear.easeNone,delay:0,onComplete:fixedUpdate});
    }
```

and this function is called by a `ENTER_FRAME` function which is `fixedUpdate()`.

I am lost right now. Any help will be deeply appreciated.

edit:
here are `fixedUpdate` and `ENTER_FRAME`

```
private function fixedUpdate(evt:Event)
{
    npcMotions();
}
```

and

```
public function init()
    {
        var random_cop_x,random_hyvn_x:Number;

        random_cop_x = randomHandler(205,300);
        random_hyvn_x = randomHandler(205,300);

        cop_bir.x = random_cop_x;
        cop_bir.y = -37;
        balik.x = random_hyvn_x;
        balik.y = -30;

        this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fixedUpdate);
    }
```

Comment: It would help if you also showed the `ENTER_FRAME` and `fixedUpdate` parts of the code. It sounds like that's where the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you added this line?

```
this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fixedUpdate);
```

`TweenLite.to` method will be fired about 24 times per second!

When animation completed and `fixedUpdate` function called you should reset `cop_bir` and `balik` `y` position to repeat animation.

P. S. You can use `repeat` parameter of TweenLite to repeat animation several times.

Comment: Also there is an endless loop as fixedUpdate calls npcMotions which will call fixedUpdate on process completion and so on... This should also be fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did not know TweenLite figures 24tps on its own. Now it makes sense.

Comment: @coner Remove the last line of the init function.